# Error "no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.4.0 (GStreamer) found"

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to build and install gst-plugin-bad-1.4.0 but I am getting following error when running the config scriptt for my Hw target.
I am running the build in my target SDK/linux-devkit/ which is installed on my Ubuntu and my HW target is an ARM-base :
This is the Error I got after I run following command on my ubuntu terminal"
./configure --host= --prefix=

Error:
configure: No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found
configure: error: no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.4.0 (GStreamer) found

I already have gstreamer-1.4.0 installed in the SDK and run fine on the target.

Any hint on what should be done?
I have also tried to install gst-plugins-base-1.4.0 but getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the dev packages installed too. I face similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51645861/building-gstreamer-editing-services-fails) and fixed it with the following

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
> ```
>
> In case GIntrospection isn't installed by default, run the following
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get build-dep gstreamer1.0
> ```

Comment: line: sudo apt-get build-dep gstreamer1.0
isnt complete. install or source ?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me even when following the instructions from the gstreamer main page (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/HowToCompileForEmbedded) to compile for embedded: ./configure --prefix="$prefix" --disable-nls --disable-static --with-html-dir=/tmp/dump

Answer (score 0):

The same issue  happens when I install gst-plugins-base-0.6.2 while the verison of gstreamer is 1.10.4.

How I solve this problem?

gst-plugins-base-1.10.2 is downded and  install successfully

Root cause:

no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.4.0 (GStreamer) found"

It means the version of gst-plugins-base must be greater than ther version of gstreamer

if the gstreamer is 1.10.2,   so the gst-plugins-base must be greater than 1.10

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).