# Building Gstreamer Editing Services fails

Tags: gstreamer

I run `./autogen.sh` inside the cloned repo and it fails saying the following:

```
configure: No package 'gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0' found
configure: error: no gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0 >= 1.14.1 (GStreamer Base Plugins) found
  configure failed
```

I have gstreamer (base, good, bad and ugly) installed on my Ubuntu. The package name that the build script looks for is `gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0` where as the system package is by the name `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base`.

Digging into the autoconf setup I found the following:

```
if test -z $GSTPB_PLUGINS_DIR; then
  GSTPB_PLUGINS_DIR=`$PKG_CONFIG --variable=pluginsdir gstreamer-plugins-base-[$1]`
  if test -z $GSTPB_PLUGINS_DIR; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR(
      [no pluginsdir set in GStreamer Base Plugins pkg-config file])
  fi
fi
```

Shouldn't it be `gstreamer[$1]-plugins-base`? Am I missing something here?

### Update:

Fixed the above by installing `libgstreamer1.0-dev` and `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev` dev packages

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

In case GIntrospection isn't installed by default, run the following

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gstreamer1.0
```

`./autogen.sh` would complete and `make && sudo make install` will run fine too.

Current status: Examples don't build stable binaries. Running c examples segfault and python example, `simple.py`, complains of missing `GES` in the namespace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 26, in <module>
    gi.require_version('GES', '1.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 130, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace GES not available
```

Just for reference: Simple.py looks like this

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GES', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gst, GES, GLib  # noqa


class Simple:
    def __init__(self, uri):
        timeline = GES.Timeline.new_audio_video()
        self.project = timeline.get_asset()

        self.project.connect("asset-added", self._asset_added_cb)
        self.project.connect("error-loading-asset", self._error_loading_asset_cb)
        self.project.create_asset(uri, GES.UriClip)
        self.layer = timeline.append_layer()
        self._create_pipeline(timeline)
        self.loop = GLib.MainLoop()

    def _create_pipeline(self, timeline):
        self.pipeline = GES.Pipeline()
        self.pipeline.set_timeline(timeline)
        bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.connect("message", self.bus_message_cb)

    def bus_message_cb(self, unused_bus, message):
        if message.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
            print("eos")
            self.loop.quit()
        elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
            error = message.parse_error()
            print("error %s" % error[1])
            self.loop.quit()

    def start(self):
        self.loop.run()

    def _asset_added_cb(self, project, asset):
        self.layer.add_asset(asset, 0, 0, Gst.SECOND * 5, GES.TrackType.UNKNOWN)
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    def _error_loading_asset_cb(self, project, error, asset_id, type):
        print("Could not load asset %s: %s" % (asset_id, error))
        self.loop.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(os.sys.argv) != 2:
        print("You must specify a file URI")
        exit(-1)

    Gst.init(None)
    GES.init()
    simple = Simple(os.sys.argv[1])
    simple.start()
```

Running the C example, simple1.c, fails with the following:

```
(simple1:15606): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:42:28.910: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(simple1:15606): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:42:28.910: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(simple1:15606): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:42:28.910: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(simple1:15606): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:42:28.910: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(simple1:15606): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:42:28.910: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
[1]    15606 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./simple1 ~/Downloads/out.mp4
```

Running gdb,

```
gst-editing-services/examples/c/simple1": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

### Update

Rebuilt the examples using Meson build system. This enabled running the bins in gdb. Got the following

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
ges_track_constructed (object=<optimized out>) at ../ges/ges-track.c:506
506         componame =
```

Indicating that it failed at ges-track.c. Relevant code below:

```
  if (self->type == GES_TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO) {
    componame =
        g_strdup_printf ("video_%s", GST_OBJECT_NAME (self->priv->composition));
  } else if (self->type == GES_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO) {
    componame = // This is where it errirs
        g_strdup_printf ("audio_%s", GST_OBJECT_NAME (self->priv->composition));
  }
```

Stepping into it line by line. The following was revealed.

```
0x00007ffff701c2cd in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fffffffc980,
    operate=0x7ffff54530d0 <dlsym_doit>, args=0x7fffffffc9f0) at dl-error-skeleton.c:194
    194     dl-error-skeleton.c: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it has to do with GES internals. Internally, glib objects are not created right and are all NULL. Why is why you have the `invalid (NULL) pointer instance`.

I was able to run the examples on my mac. Package mismatches seems to be the issue here.